# How to make material ui icon clickable and redirect to url

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make GitHub icon `<GitHubIcon />` clickable and make it redirect to external url, looking in the api it doesn't seem to have link prop ... https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
        Made with <FavoriteIcon /> by
        <a href="https://github.com/quiko"><GitHubIcon /></a>  //Not working 
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
</div>
```

How is it done usually ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this:

```js
<GitHubIcon onClick={handlePageChange} />
```

and on the function definition:

```js
const handlePageChange() {
window.location.href="pagelink"
}
```

or directly using an arrow function:

```js
<GitHubIcon onClick={event =>  window.location.href='pagelink'} />
```

If looking to add effects on hover with material-ui styles:

---

**How to add stlyes on Material-UI:**

Import makeStyles:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Create the class:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  clickableIcon: {
    color: 'green',
    '&:hover': {
    color: 'yellow',
    },
  },
}));
```

Add the API call on your function declaration:

```js
  const classes = useStyles();
```

And add this class to your element:

```js
<GitHubIcon 
onClick={event =>  window.location.href='pagelink'} 
className={classes.clickableIcon}
/>
```

You could also use directly a css file.

I'm not really happy with css styling over material-ui api, specially because this horrible CSS-in-JS syntaxi, but it works well, here you'll find some documentation: [Material-ui Styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api)

Comment: Thanks, it does redirect now to the url but still not show that the icon is clickable when hover over it ..

Comment: @yuri: it does open the url in the same window. Is there anyway that we can make it open in a new window ? Thanks

Comment: Use window.open instead of window.location:
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');